# ember.js - define route with optional parameter and default model

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I want to define a route in emberjs, that has an optional parameter
eg:

`/video`
and
`/video/123`

if no parameter is supplied, I want to use a default model/fixture.
if a parameter is supplied, then I want to obviously lookup the model using the parameter.

if I then go to a different route, and return to the route without the parameter, I want to use the previously loaded model.

eg:

`startup app`

`/video` - shows my default/fixture model

`/video/123` - shows model 123

`/another-route` - shows new route

`/video` - shows model 123

is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a clean way to do this, although it is slightly "tricky". The idea is to use a nested route to hold the id, but not render it, instead having the parent route be responsible for rendering it using the render helper. When you do it this way, all the logic can live in VideoChoiceController, and it will be used for displaying either the default video or a specific one. When doing it this way, there is no need to explicitly "remember" the last video, the state machine that the route engine represents does it for you.

```
App.Router.map(function) {
  this.resource('video', function(){
    this.route('choice', {path: ':video_id'});
  });
});

App.VideoRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return App.get('defaultVideo');
  },

  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    var video_choice = this.controllerFor('video.choice')

    // this is necessary if you want, for example,
    // to display the name or a link to the default video
    // when a specific video is being displayed
    controller.set('model', model);

    if(Ember.isEmpty(video_choice.get('model'))){
      video_choice.set('model', model);
    }
  }
});

App.VideoChoiceRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return this.get('store').find('video', params.video_id);
  },

  renderTemplate: function() {
    // if you don't override renderTemplate to do nothing, 
    // everything will still work but you will get an assertion
    // error that render should only be used once with a
    // singleton controller
  }
});



<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  <div>
    {{outlet}}
  </div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name='video'>
  <div> attrributes here always refer to the default video: {{name}} </div>
  {{render "video.choice"}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name='video'>
  <div> 
    attrributes here always refer to specific or last video, 
    or default if a specific video has never been loaded: {{name}}
  </div>
</script>
```

Comment: the reason i refer to this as slightly tricky is that it relies on the fact that changing routes tears down the old routes template but doesn't clear its controller, a nuance that I'm not sure is intended to be exploited.

Comment: there is another way to do this, using the video/index route and having the video/index template do a `{{render 'video.choice' defaultVideo}}`. Then you can have VideoChoiceRoute render as normal. This might actually be better & less "tricky".

Comment: A review of my response would be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 7):

I ended up using a different solution:

```
  this.resource('video', function() {
    this.route('index', {path: '/'});
    this.route('item', {path: ':id'});
  });
```

These routes support:

`/video` - shows my default/fixture model

`/video/123` - shows model 123

When the user access to `/video`, the VideoIndexRoute must redirect to VideoItemRoute without any id.

```
var VideoIndexRoute = Em.Route.extend({

  afterModel: function() {

    // this is the tricky part
    this.replaceWith('video.item', '');

  }

});
```

Now, the VideoItemRoute must check if there is any model associated, and when it is missing, it should use the default fixtures or a new one.

```
var VideoItemRoute = Em.Route.extend({

  model: function(param) {
    if (param.id) {
      return this.store.find('video', param.id);
    }
  },

  setupController: function (controller, model) {
    if (!model) {
      model = this.store.createRecord('video',{
        name: 'default Name'
      });
      // or use fixture...
    }
    this._super(controller, model);

  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Definitely, you'll have to do something a little funky, like storing the last video in some global variable, but that's up to you.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/uhoQozu/1/edit

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/uhoQozu/1#/video

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/uhoQozu/1#/video/32

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('videoModel', {path:'/video/:video_id'});
  this.resource('video');  // this resource can be accessed at /video
});
```

Comment: you're leaving out a lot of stuff he'll have to do to make it work this way, like specifiying which template to render in `renderTemplate`, and handling the duplication between the videoModel and video controllers etc.

Comment: A review of my response would be appreciated, thanks